# How do you replace all strings that are not between two characters?

Tags: java, string, replace

Example (replacing 'text' with '...'):

Before:
text(text)text

After:
...(text)...

Comment: People appreciate if you show that you've tried to solve the problem yourself.  Maybe show some code that you tried that isn't working correctly, or explain your thinking about what you COULD do.  It just sounds like you're asking someone else to do your homework if you don't show any attempt yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is easier to find what you want to keep, and replace the rest.

E.g. like this:

```
static String abbreviate(String input, String openTag, String closeTag) {
    String regex = Pattern.quote(openTag) + ".*?" + Pattern.quote(closeTag);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    int start = 0;
    for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input); m.find(); start = m.end()) {
        if (start < m.start())
            buf.append("...");
        buf.append(m.group());
    }
    if (start < input.length())
        buf.append("...");
    return buf.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(abbreviate("text(text)text(text)text", "(", ")"));
System.out.println(abbreviate("text$text$text$text$text$text", "$", "$"));
System.out.println(abbreviate("text(text)text", ")", "("));
```

*Output*

```
...(text)...(text)...
...$text$...$text$...
...
```

Comment: +1. Fabulous answer as usual! I was thinking, `if (start < input.length())
   return input;` would have been more appropriate. What do you say?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, that would fail. Try it with the 3 test cases shown here and see for yourself. They would all 3 return `input` unchanged, because the condition is true for all 3 of them, otherwise you wouldn't get the final `...`. --- You could add `if (start == 0) return "...";`, but that's just a minor performance improvement, and would be incorrect for input `""`.

Comment: Got it...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the characters and only append those that are between the two specified characters. This can be done as follows:

```
private String splitStr(String str, char first, char second) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(str.isEmpty() || str.indexOf(first) < 0 || str.indexOf(second) < 0)
            return sb.toString();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        boolean append = false;
        for(char c : chars) {
            if(c == first) {
                sb.append(c);
                append = true;
            }else if(c == second) {
                sb.append(c);
                append = false;
            }else if(append)
                sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Some sample cases are:

```
"text(text)text(text)text(text)text" => "(text)(text)(text)"
```

```
"text(text)text" => "(text)"
```

Comment: The question title says "replace **all** strings", implying that there can be multiple pairs of characters, e.g. `"text(text)text(text)text(text)text"`, so that won't work.

Answer (score -2):

```
String s = "text(text)text";
String newString = s.replace("text", "...");
System.out.println(newString);      //returns ...(...)...
```

1. Note that "(text)" still contains "text", the braces around it will not stop it from being replaced.
2. You need to assign the result to a new String to use it. Strings are [immutable](https://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string)

Comment: An answer that returns `...(...)...` when question specifically states that it should return `...(text)...` is not a useful answer.